# Is the distance traveled by a continuous time random walk on the integers bounded by a Poisson random variable?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a continuous time random walk of a single particle on the integers of the following form:

\begin{eqnarray}
X_t= S_{N_t}, \ \ X_0=0
\end{eqnarray}
where $S_n$ is a discrete time random walk on the integers (with probability $p$ of moving right one increment at each step and probability $q=1-p$ of moving left) and $N_t$ is a poisson process of rate $1$.

I am trying to figure out whether $\exists \ c>0$ such that:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(S_{N_t}=n)\leq \frac{e^{-ct}(ct)^n}{n!}
\end{eqnarray}

Is the $p=1/2$ case special?

Comment: Is $N_t$ independent of $S_n$?  If so, then since there are closed form expressions for the probabilities $P(S_k = n)$ and $P(N_t = k)$ you should be able to compute this exactly by conditioning on $N_t$.

Comment: Ah yes, they are indeed independent. I'm having trouble manipulating the closed form expressions as an infinite number of jumps can occur to realize the same displacement.

Comment: For fixed $k$, there are only finitely many possibilities for the $k$ jumps to realize a particular displacement.  Indeed, $S_k$ has something closely related to a Bernoulli distribution.  This is the benefit of conditioning on $N_t$.